# How to make dump data only from selected tables without schema

Tags: mysql, sql

First I have make it one sql file for only schema get of 64 tables.

Code :

```
       mysqldump -p<password>  --no-data database > schema.sql
```

Here, sql file create without data in that file 64 tables now i only need 15 table data from database without schema and create new sql file.

I try my self but it not working.

Code:

```
  mysqldump  -p<password> database --ignore-table=database.table1 --ignore-table=database.table2 > data.sql
```

Any merge both file any apply to new database.

Please if any idea so give me some advice.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) for tasks like this - which has a gui and is much simpler for beginners than the commandline.

Also [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/de/products/workbench/) is another gui tool.